# Where clause containing dots extension in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I have a question which is to select values from my DB. I have a where clause like this :

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM liquid 
          WHERE Id = '.$id.' 
          AND (
                    picone = tiger-1477927129.jpg OR 
                    pictwo = tiger-1477927129.jpg 
                    OR picthree = tiger-1477927129.jpg 
                    ' . 'picfour = tiger-1477927129.jpg 
                    OR picfive = tiger-1477927129.jpg
                    OR picsix = tiger-1477927129.jpg
          )';
```

The problem is I have dots before the file extension, so sql does not execute this. Do you know how could I solve this?

Thanks
Lee

Comment: Looks awful.  Are you aware that MySQL requires (single) quotes around string constants?

Comment: You need to learn basic SQL syntax... And if you think the dots are a problem, imagine what those `-` are causing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use quotes around the values i.e. `image='image.jpg'` and you will need to escape the quotes for the string in PHP

```
 $query = 'SELECT * FROM liquid WHERE
    Id = '.$id.'
    AND (
        picone = \'tiger-1477927129.jpg\'
        OR pictwo = \'tiger-1477927129.jpg\'
        OR picthree = \'tiger-1477927129.jpg\'
        OR picfour = \'tiger-1477927129.jpg\'
        OR picfive = \'tiger-1477927129.jpg\'
        OR picsix = \'tiger-1477927129.jpg\'
    )
';
```

Comment: Could encapsulate in double quotes then the concatenation and escaping can be removed.

Comment: thank all of you. :)